# Add equations that flows with the text in the keynote

Tags: keynote

I'd like to make some slides with equations using Keynote. The standard way is to leave some blanks for the formula among the text, and cover the blanks with the LatexIT formulas. Since the formula does not flow with the text, if I need to modify the text by adding a word in the middle, then all the blanks after the word are shifted and I need to shift all the formula one by one manually to match the blanks. This is headache when there are lots of formula.

I am asking if there is a way to let the formula flow together with the text so that I do not need to manually shift the formula one by one? Even better, whether it is possible to add equations directly in the text without leaving the blanks first?

I am using the keynote on the MacBook Pro (MacOS Mojave 10.14.6). The keynote version is 9.0.1 (6196).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of having equations flow with the text is to use the [equation editor](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/add-mathematical-equations-tan72a69d01f/mac) inside Keynote to create equations.

You can use **Insert > Equation** menu at the top of Keynote or press <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to activate the equation edtior.

The equation editor in Keynote supports both LaTeX and MathML. See this [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/add-mathematical-equations-tan72a69d01f/mac) for more details.

Below is an example Keynote slide that includes an equation created with the equation editor:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but this does not work for me. I tried to create a text box, and insert -> equation. After I typed the equation and clicked "insert", the equation shows in the middle of the slide, rather than in the text box.

Comment: I also tried to follow the instructions in https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/place-objects-inside-a-text-box-or-shape-tan3ab53d680/10.0/mac/1.0. The way there is to first cut an equation, and paste into the text box where I want to place it. However, after I used command+X to cut the equation, I simply can not paste it into the text box because inside the text box, the paste button is simply greyed out.

Comment: You don't need a text box. The objects created by the equation editor behave / are treated like objects that flow with all the other characters in a sentence / bullet. Just press **Alt+Command+E** whenever you need an equation in a sentence / bullet, type the equation into the equation editor window that pops up in, for example, LaTeX format and then click on **Insert** when completed. Then just continue writing your sentence / bullet or complete it whichever is necessary. I will update my answer with an example slide including an equation created with this method.

Comment: However, if you wish, you can also create an equation from inside a text box using the equation edtior and place it in the text box. Just click once on the text box after creating it and then press **Alt+Command+E** and write your equation and then click on **Insert**. I reckon you tried to insert an equation without clicking on the text box first after creating the text box and this has led to the equation showing up in the middle of the slide instead of the text box.

Comment: Thank you Alper! I figure this is the problem of the version. In the pop-up window, I checked the ? mark on the bottom-left, and it showed in the second point that "The equation appears in the center of the slide. You can move the equation, resize it, copy it, or delete it.". So I figure that I may have a different version of keynote than yours. Could you tell me your version? Thanks!

Comment: After updating to the latest version, it finally creates the inline equations. Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: Happy to hear that you were able to figure this out! Thx for letting me know. Keynote version I used to create the example slide in my answer was v9.1. I checked that remark you have quoted from Keynote Help for v9.1 but I think is a bit misleading as is. It should have rather said (included) "The equation appears at the insertion point or replaces selected text. If neither is true, then the equation appears..."

Comment: I've just ased [How to include equations in-line with text within the cell of a table in Keynote?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/399987/143729)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Start writing your sentence or phrase until you get to where you need to show an equation and at that position go to insert equation and type your equation. When finished entering it, click on the insert button in the equation editor and then continue typing as normal. This puts equation in-line with your text.

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but this does not work for me. I tried to create a text box, and insert -> equation. After I typed the equation and clicked "insert", the equation shows in the middle of the slide, rather than in the text box.

Comment: I've just ased [How to include equations in-line with text within the cell of a table in Keynote?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/399987/143729)