# How to include equations in-line with text within the cell of a table in Keynote?

Tags: keynote

Answers to [Add equations that flows with the text in the keynote](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387566/143729) explain that in Keynote we can insert an in-line equation when typing text. I use option-command-E or the same from pull-down Insert menu and it works fine for text in a text object.

**However:** when I'm writing text *inside of a cell of a table* this fails. No matter what I do the equation pops out of the text and becomes a floating equation.

If I copy a line of text that contains an in-line equation and paste it inside the cell of a table, the text appears but the equation is dropped.

Is there any way to include equations in-line with text within the cell of a table in Keynote?

`Keynote version 9.2.1 (6529)`

`\int_0^{n\pi}\cos(ax^n)`

[image: Is there any way to include equations in-line with text within the cell of a table in Keynote?]

Comment: I know, I forgot the *dx* in the integral, that must be it! :-)

Comment: Be sure to teach us what you learned in an answer. I know this error will hit others.

Comment: @bmike oh my tongue-in-cheek humor is obscure. Of course just because I left off the *dx* in the integral would not cause Keynote to reject the whole equation! I have no idea why this won't work,

Comment: I thought you were about to provide a fix and I didn’t understand the comment.

Comment: I thought I had this... works in Pages.  Works in Keynote *without* a table.  When I create a table and try it ... I also get a floating equation (detached from cell text).  <sigh>  Suggest you visit apple.com/feedback

Comment: @TimCampbell thanks for that! I can reproduce your findings; I can do this in a table in Pages. When I copy the table in the Pages document and paste it into a Notes document *the in-line equation again disappears!* This looks to me to be intentional; Keynote simply doesn't want to deal with this. It turns out that switching applications and using Pages is a workable solution for me; I need to show this table in a document both in email and with a projector, but I can do both with a Pages document.

Comment: @TimCampbell Would you consider posting the switch to Pages as a tentative and/or partial answer? I think it's may certainly be helpful for future readers to know that all is not lost and a workaround exists, albeit suboptimal. I won't accept the answer any time soon as it's not conclusive and complete, but I think it's useful enough to future readers to make it known. *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh I can. One caveat (kind of a big one) is that after creating the table in Pages with a cell that includes text and equation, if I then try to copy the table onto a Keynote slide, the equation gets left behind.

Comment: @TimCampbell ya [I saw that too](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399987/how-to-include-equations-in-line-with-text-within-the-cell-of-a-table-in-keynote?noredirect=1#comment553685_399987) which is why the suggestion to [switch to Pages (would have to be) a tentative and/or partial answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399987/how-to-include-equations-in-line-with-text-within-the-cell-of-a-table-in-keynote?noredirect=1#comment553686_399987)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to have an equation created by the equation editor (Insert > Equation menu from the top) inline with text inside a table cell in Keynote. This is possible in Pages but not in Keynote.

The problem stems from a Keynote table not being allowed to accept a picture as a text element in a cell. This behavior leads to an equation not being accepted inside a table cell as a text element in Keynote because an output of the equation editor is handled as a picture by the programs in the iWork suite (Numbers, Pages, Keynote).

A partial solution to this problem within Keynote is to create all of the contents of a cell using the equation editor and paste it inside the corresponding cell (automatically as a picture). The appearance of each "equation" picture can then be adjusted using Format > Cell > Fill menu on the sidebar on the right as shown in the example below (Keynote v10.1). Note that, once pasted, one can not edit the equation picture in a cell. If any change is needed to a cell with an equation, then the whole "equation" needs to be re-created and pasted into the corresponding cell.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give this a try today.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [What language is used in equations in Pages and Keynote? e.g. \texttt{}, \mathtt{}, \tt{} and \text{}](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/400446/143729)

Comment: This language is called [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). It is a typesetting language which is widely used in the scientific publishing community. You can also use [MathML](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a clean answer (does not solve the issue presented in the original question) but I'll post what I've learned and possibly an alternative.

When I test this using Keynote (v10.1) I see the same behavior ...

If I create a simple text box, I can perform an `Insert` -> `Equation...` in mid sentence and this works provided the text is not in a table cell.

If I perform the same action inside a table cell, the equation becomes a floating element (no longer tied to the text or cell).

If I perform the same action in Pages (v10.1) this works correctly *even* within a table.

[image: LaTeX equation embedded within text inside a table cell]

The bad news is that if I then attempt to copy this table onto a Keynote slide, the equation is dropped.

This *seems* like a bug considering it is implemented as expected in Pages ... but Keynote has an issue with it.

You can send feedback to Apple here:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/keynote.html

Comment: *Thank you for your informative post!* I've tried this and I get the same behavior as well. For my current need I can actually switch to using Pages so that can be a workaround for me at the moment, but I'll keep this question open until a more definitive conclusion can be reached.